# How to find 2 lowest values for each item in an SQL table, order by attribute

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I have 3 tables as follows:

1. Product: (product_id, product_description)
2. Seller: (seller_id, seller_name)
3. Association: (seller_id, product_id, price)

Many sellers sell many products. I need to find the two cheapest prices for each product (ordered by increasing price) and their corresponding vendors. The ideal column outputs are:

```
product_id, product_description, seller_id, seller_name, price

p01, milk, s04, walmart, 1.50

p01, milk, s02, target, 2.25

p02, rice, s05, safeway, 1.30

p02, rice, s03, dillons, 1.75
```

Here's what I've tried on SQL-server; it's an intermediate step towards the answer. I'm triggering an error but don't understand why:

```
SELECT TOP 2 *
FROM

    (SELECT A.seller_id, A.product_id, min(price) AS A.price
    FROM Association A
    GROUP BY A.seller_ID, A.product_id)

    ORDER BY A.price ASC
```

And the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Edit: I used the solution proposed by Benjamin; it's near correct. Here's the query output:

```sql
seller_id, product_id, price, m
1   1   7.89    1
3   1   8.00    1
6   1   8.50    1
1   2   12.05   1
6   2   12.50   1
1   3   13.67   1
6   3   15.00   1
1   4   7.66    1
3   4   7.50    1
6   4   8.24    1
```

Of note, some product_id values, such as 1 and 4, occurred 3 times, where I only need the two lowest prices, not the third (or higher.) So I believe that this code is ordering by price, but not removing entries with a price higher than the second lowest.

Answer (score 1):

Its easier to do it with a CTE:

```
with min1 as (
SELECT A.seller_id, A.product_id,  A.price,
row_number() over (partition by  A.seller_id, A.product_id order by a.price   asc) as rn
    FROM Association A
    )
select * from min1 
   where rn <3 
   order by   seller_id,  product_id, price;
```

Comment: I think this is almost what I need it to perform. The query output a column "m" which I wasn't expecting. Additionally, I believes it's sorting by price accurately, but not removing rows after the 2nd lowest price (i.e. the third lowest is displayed for product_id = 1, 4)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you have a derived table in your query (which some might call a subquery). It must have an alias - so give it one.

In the query used to form the derived table, you have used incorrect syntax. You should not attempt to give the aggregated column the name of a.price (and you SHOULD be consistent with your names and their spelling - one day this inconsistency will bite you). Why? Well, first it is the source of your error. If you want the column to be named "a.price", then you need to delimit it since it violates the rules for regular identifiers. But don't - the period (or dot) has a specific meaning / usage and using it in the column name is very, VERY misleading. So just give it an alias without the period.

```
... (select A.seller_id, A.product_id, min(A.price) as minprice 
from ... ) as MinAssoc
```

As you can see in this snippet, I gave the derived table the alias "MinAssoc" - which is the first thing I mentioned. If you leave it out, you will encounter an error if you just fix the column alias problem.

Next, stop using single letter aliases. That is just lazy. Sure, this is a short example and it is easy to see what your code does NOW. But you are building and reinforcing habits that will not serve you well and it reflects poorly on your work when others see it and need to decipher more complicated queries (because a single letter doesn't provide any help to understanding the "thing" a row represents).

These will fix your errors but you will need to use a different approach to your goal - as already suggested.

Comment: Single letter aliases are extremely common and widely used by many who are recognized as experts in TSQL.  I would like to see you work out a complete solution as a subquery. Before CTE's we had to use sub-queries but since CTE's my solution is the more common one.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive it using [`ROW_NUMBER () OVER` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) either in SUB-QUERY or CTE, following is the sub-query example:

and the error due to `AS A.price` which supposed to be `AS price` in your example.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT A.seller_id, 
            A.product_id, 
            price,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  A.seller_id, A.product_id order by a.price) as RN
    FROM  Association A
   ) as T
Where T.RN <=2
ORDER BY price ASC
```